# How to process twilio SMS status callback in java

Tags: java, spring, twilio

I have following service method for SMS callback processing

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void processSms(@RequestParam(value = "MessageStatus", required = false) String messageStatus,
                       @RequestParam(value = "ApiVersion", required = false) String apiVersion,
                       @RequestParam(value = "SmsSid", required = false) String smsSid,
                       @RequestParam(value = "SmsStatus", required = false) String smsStatus,
                       @RequestParam(value = "To", required = false) String to,
                       @RequestParam(value = "From", required = false) String from,
                       @RequestParam(value = "MessageSid", required = false) String messageSid,
                       @RequestParam(value = "AccountSid", required = false) String accountSid){

    TwilioCallBackResponse response = new TwilioCallBackResponse();
    response.messageStatus = messageStatus;
    response.apiVersion = apiVersion;
    response.smsSid = smsSid;
    response.smsStatus = smsStatus;
    response.to = to;
    response.from = from;
    response.messageSid = messageSid;
    response.accountSid = accountSid;

    LOG.info("Incomming twilio callback: " + response.messageStatus);

    smsService.processSmsCallback(response);
}
```

I can get and log response from twilio successfully. 
Problem is that in twilio end response error is logged. Should I specify  content type or respond with some response body? Any ideas?

This is from twilio log

[image]

and error 11200 HTTP retrieval failure is also logged

Answer (score 4):

Status callbacks do not control application flow, so TwiML does not need to be returned in this instance; however, it's recommended that you [respond to status callbacks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200#possible-solutions) with either a 204 No Content or a 200 OK with Content-Type: text/xml and an empty `<Response/>` in the body. Failure to respond properly will result in warnings in Debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, based on Jim answer this is what works for me and no more warnings on twilio side

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/xml")
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String processSms(@RequestParam(value = "MessageStatus", required = false) String messageStatus,
                       @RequestParam(value = "ApiVersion", required = false) String apiVersion,
                       @RequestParam(value = "SmsSid", required = false) String smsSid,
                       @RequestParam(value = "SmsStatus", required = false) String smsStatus,
                       @RequestParam(value = "To", required = false) String to,
                       @RequestParam(value = "From", required = false) String from,
                       @RequestParam(value = "MessageSid", required = false) String messageSid,
                       @RequestParam(value = "AccountSid", required = false) String accountSid){

    TwilioCallBackResponse response = new TwilioCallBackResponse();
    response.messageStatus = messageStatus;
    response.apiVersion = apiVersion;
    response.smsSid = smsSid;
    response.smsStatus = smsStatus;
    response.to = to;
    response.from = from;
    response.messageSid = messageSid;
    response.accountSid = accountSid;

    LOG.info("Incomming twilio callback: " + JsonUtils.printJson(response));

    smsService.processSmsCallback(response);

    return "<Response/>";
}
```